# Iterating through yml file and storing the values in variable

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to iterate through yml files which have data in this format
this file name is artifact.yml

```
artifacts:
    - name: feture1
      version: 2.0.5
      git_url: git@somethign:tmm/tmm.git
    - name: feture2
      version: 1.0
      git_url: git@123.git
```

My end gole is to fetch the version and name from this file and store it in a variable for further use.

i have tried using the yml module (snap of code i am trying)

```
import yaml

op = open('artifact.yml')

myyml = yaml.safe_load(op)

for i in myyml['artifacts']:
        print (i)

op.close()
```

the output i am getting is this.

```
{'name': 'feture1', 'version': '2.0.5', 'git_url': 'git@somethign:tmm/tmm.git'}
{'name': 'feture2', 'version': 1.0, 'git_url': 'git@123.git'}
```

but i am not sure how to separate out the below two dictionaries and store the name and version in a separate variable

also i have tried something like this

```
myyml['artifacts'][0])
```

the output is

```
{'name': 'feture1', 'version': '2.0.5', 'git_url': 'git@somethign:tmm/tmm.git'}
```

but the problem is i will not be aware that how many elements will be there, as i parse it so also need some way to make this effective regardless of the number of entries in the yml file  (FYI, the yml source format is same what i have given on top it is just that the number of entries could be more or less)

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

using `myyml['artifacts'][0])` is giving you a map
then all you have to do is giving it a key and get the desired value

```
myyml['artifacts'][0]["name"])
myyml['artifacts'][0]["version"])
```

Comment: yes this is what i was looking for ...thanks Noor for your help.
and just to let anyone looking this question i used len to find out the number of values in the file and used that number to iterate .
example:
print (len(myyml['artifacts']))